# inserting and retrieving mobile number into database in android

Tags: android, database

```
    n1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num1);
    int no1 = Integer.parseInt(n1.getText().toString());
    n2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num2);
    int no2 = Integer.parseInt(n2.getText().toString());
    message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);
    String msg = message.getText().toString();
    settings.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS settingtb(mob1 LONG,mob2 LONG,time VARCHAR,message VARCHAR(1000));");
    settings.execSQL("INSERT INTO settingtb VALUES('" + no1 + "','" + no2
            + "'," + time + ",'" + msg + "');");
```

data is inserted into database if the mob1,mob2 values are less than 10 values if it exceed 9 values im getting numberformat exception

here is my logcat

```
09-24 18:16:23.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1656): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-24 18:16:23.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1656): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "7842334531"
09-24 18:16:23.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1656):     at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
09-24 18:16:23.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1656):     at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:378)
09-24 18:16:23.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1656):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
09-24 18:16:23.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1656):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
09-24 18:16:23.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1656):     at com.example.esha.settings.calltable(settings.java:87)
09-24 18:16:23.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1656):     at com.example.esha.settings$1.onClick(settings.java:76)
09-24 18:16:23.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1656):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
09-24 18:16:23.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1656):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
09-24 18:16:23.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1656):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-24 18:16:23.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1656):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-24 18:16:23.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1656):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-24 18:16:23.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1656):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-24 18:16:23.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1656):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-24 18:16:23.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1656):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-24 18:16:23.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1656):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-24 18:16:23.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1656):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-24 18:16:23.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1656):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: now you want user have to enter 10 numbers for mobile? Correct?

Comment: yes.and i want to insert it to database and to retrieve also plz see my logcat

Comment: Catch the exception by putting try/catch and display the toast message to user that "Invalid Mobile Number" like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your this integer variable into long as below,

```
long no2 = Long.parseLong(n2.getText().toString().trim());
```

You are inserting values in wrong way, you are inserting String value in mob1 & mob2 fields, Convert it in to number as follows,

```
settings.execSQL("INSERT INTO settingtb VALUES(" + no1 + "," + no2
            + "," + time + ",'" + msg + "');");
```

You don't need to add `'` when you are inserting numeric value.

Also when you are fetching the values, you are doing wrong, you are accessing everything in integer variable ??? change it according as follows,

```
c.moveToFirst();  
     if(c!=null)
     {
      do{
        long c1 = c.getColumnIndex("mob1");
        long c2 = c.getColumnIndex("mob2");
        String c3 = c.getColumnIndex("time");
        String c4 = c.getColumnIndex("message");

        s1 = c.getString(c1);
        s2 = c.getString(c2);
        s3 = c.getString(c3);
        s4 = c.getString(c4);
```

Comment: i tried it also but i'm getting force close plz see my logcat

Comment: there is no problem with retrieving problem is at inserting the 10 digit mobile number into database

Answer (score 0):

very simple..actaully just use Double a datatype instead of long

Answer (score 0):

Does your exception occur at this line: "s3 = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c3));"?

You are probably exceeding the **int** range: -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. Try using a **long** for storing the phone number.

**Edit**:

Replace this line:

```
s3 = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c3));
```

With this one:

```
long s3Long = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c3));
```

Comment: Where exactly does your exception occur? the stacktrace doesn't help much, as we can't see the lines' number. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: i'm facing problem at insert statement